# JQuery datatable: set fixed header and width

Tags: jquery, datatable

Need help.

I am using datatable jquery plugin. I have put the below code to get fixed header but still I don't see a vertical scrollbar. Can anyone please help.

```
"fixedHeader": {
                    header: true,
             },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put these two lines. You can change height and width as you want.

```
scrollY: '100px',
scrollX: '200px',
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/), this is how it's used:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```